# will workflow actions available for all the s objects

Tags: workflow

An iterviwer asked me one question in an interview that will all workflow actions performs on all S-Objects. I said yes but he didn't satisfied for my answer. kindly help me out somebody.

Answer (score 3):

No. Most "normal" SObjects can have workflows, such as Accounts and Contacts. Special SObjects, like AccountShare, can't have custom fields, triggers, workflow rules, etc. Other SObjects, like Tasks, have only limited workflow functionality. Many "setup" SObjects also don't support workflow rules.